# How to detect additional mime type in Golang

Tags: go, mime-types, detection

There are `http.DetectContentType([]byte)` function in `net/http` package. But only limited number of types are supported. How to add support of `docx`, `doc`, `xls`, `xlsx`, `ppt`, `pps`, `odt`, `ods`, `odp` files not by extension, but by the content.
As far as I know, there are some problems, because `docx`/`xlsx`/`pptx`/`odp`/`odt` files has the same signature as the `zip` file (50 4B 03 04).

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/mime/

Comment: @SalvadorDali The mime package is useful, but the question specifically asks about detection based on content, not extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [mimetype](https://github.com/gabriel-vasile/mimetype).

For anyone having the same problem 3 years later, nowadays the packages for mime type detection based on the content are the following:

- [filetype](https://github.com/h2non/filetype)

  - pure go, no c bindings
  - can be extented to detect new mime types
  - has issues with files which pass as more than one mime type (ex: xlsx and docx passing as zip) because it stores matching functions in a map, thus it does not guarantee the order of traversal
  - limited number of detected mime types
- [magicmime](https://github.com/rakyll/magicmime)

  - needs libmagic-dev installed
  - of the 3, it has highest number of detected mime types
  - can be extended, albeit harder... `man magic`
  - libmagic is not thread safe
- [mimetype](https://github.com/gabriel-vasile/mimetype)

  - pure go, no c bindings
  - higher number of detected mime types than `filetype`
  - is thread safe
  - can be extended

Answer (score 2):

For files with `x` at the end are relatively easy to detect. Just unzip it and read `.rels/_rels` file. It contains path to the main file in document. It denoted by namespace `http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument`. Just check its name. It's `document.xml` for docx, `workbook.xml` for xlsx and `presentation.xml` for pptx.

More info here can be found here [ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm).

Binary formats harder to detect. Basically you need to read [MS-CFB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942138.aspx) filesystem and check for entries:

- `WordDocument` for doc
- `Workbook` or `Book` for xls
- `PowerPoint Document` for ppt
- `EncryptedPackage` means file is encrypted.

Comment: any tips on how to get started with this?

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way to extend `http.DetectContentType` as it uses a fixed, unexported slice of "sniffers": https://golang.org/src/net/http/sniff.go (`sniffSignatures` on line 49 at the time of writing).

Also, I looked quickly through godoc.org in search of a better package but didn't find any that is extensible and content-oriented as you require.

My advice would be: build your own package, guided by Go's content sniffer implementation (which follows https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/).

Edit: If you're willing to use CGO and you're on nix, you could use libmagic bindings like for example https://github.com/jteeuwen/magic.

Answer (score 1):

I found [mimemagic](https://bitbucket.org/taruti/mimemagic), which I find preferable to [magicmime](https://github.com/rakyll/magicmime) since it doesn't use cgo. But magicmime is better at differentiating between application/zip and office file types.