# showing wrong mime type in go

Tags: go, mime-types

I am really new to Go. Here's my code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fileBytes, _ := os.ReadFile(os.Args[len(os.Args)-1])
    fileDetails := http.DetectContentType(fileBytes)
    mimeType := strings.Split(fileDetails, ";")[0]
    base64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(fileBytes)

    fmt.Print("data:" + mimeType + ";base64," + base64)
}
```

This returns correct mime type for other file types but for svg it shows `text/plain`. I don't know much about `http` module. I am using linux. Can I set mime type for svg?

Comment: `DetectContentType` implements https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/ which does not define how SVG should be detected (apart from that I get text/xml). For alternative approaches see [How to detect additional mime type in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838185/how-to-detect-additional-mime-type-in-golang)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with detecting SVG was [opened](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15888) in 2016 and closed without any changes, because [DetectContentType](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/net/http/sniff.go;l=21;bpv=0;bpt=1) function implements [mimesniff](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/) detection algorithm. The mimesniff specification doesn't define SVG. There was another issue in [mimesniff](https://github.com/whatwg/mimesniff/issues/7) project that proposed to add SVG detection algorithm, but it was declined.

[Steffen Ulrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich) already mentioned that you can use alternative approaches described in [How to detect additional mime type in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838185/how-to-detect-additional-mime-type-in-golang) : [filetype](https://github.com/h2non/filetype), [magicmime](https://github.com/rakyll/magicmime) and [mimetype](https://github.com/gabriel-vasile/mimetype)